# SP Smart Slider doesn't load

Tags: joomla-2.5, jquery

If you check this webpage: http://www.benaventegrow.com/ I don't know why, but SP Smart Slider module doesn't load.

It must be a JQuery conflict. I have read about the `.noConflict()` function, but it's already implemented in the jquery code.

When I disable the Jquery VirtueMart option, it works, but in shop, the prices don't update when I choose another product. If I active it, the slider doesn't work, but the prices do.

What should I do? I need the prices and the slider working.

P.S. In the console, I am receiving this:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
spiStoreiiLayout.spSmartslider({
 autoplay  : 1,
 interval  : 7000,
 delay     : 0, 
 fullWidth : false
});
```

It's marking the delay option (with value 0).

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the JS within the `<script>` tags in the browser console, I can't seem to find anything wrong, however I did notice you have 2 instances of jQuery being imported.

The first one from the K2 extension, and the other one from GoogleApis CDN but as it's external, I don't know where it's being called from. The one coming from Google os an older version so I would suggest trying to remove this one.

It could possibly be being called from the Smart Slider extension, so check the options for it and see if there is anything relating to disabling jQuery.

If push comes to shove, then I would recommend using [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy), which is a plugin that strips out all instances of jQuery and uses it's own, along with many other features.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried removing Google Apis, but It didnt work. Now, I've just downloaded JQuery Easy, but I have completely no idea about how to use it

Comment: Please read the documentation for it. All that should be done is you enable the plugin and define the version of jQuery that you wish to use

Comment: OK, I did it. I downloaded Jquery 1.11.2, I put the path of the file. I enabled the plugin, and i disabled Google Apis, and It still doesnt work. I have also tried disabling JQuery VirtueMart. But Slider only works when ALL Jquery files (plugin, virtuemart and google apis) are disabled... It's really annoying. I have no idea what it is. I tried to look for any setting in the Slider about Jquery, but i found nothing... So... what could it be?

Comment: You don't need to download jQuery, you can import it via CDN which is the preferred method. My guess would be to fiddle around with some of the VirtueMart options and see if anything gets fixed without completely removing it.

Comment: Those are the options you can enable/disable... I have tried all, I guess http://gyazo.com/ef6bed680f75b6106576356c5e4a1fa0

Comment: Which of the options did you disable to get the slider working? The Ajax one?

Comment: The ones you see disabled. But If I disable those ones, in the shop, prices doesn't update

Comment: So, do you know what could it be? I need help real fast

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. As you already know, it's something to do with the virtuemart script itself or a conflict between the 2 scripts, however unfortunately, I do not have time to start debugging it in depth. If this is urgent, then I would suggest using a different slider as there are many extensions out there that will provide you with the same features